# Please do not be too quick to judge and Downvote!

Tags: discussion

My request is regarding [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/808/38) question. This user seems to be "not-so-good" in English. Hence, initially his question came off as offensive. But, after some inquiry in comments, the question was edit properly. By then, there was already two down votes.

People, please don't jump to down vote and be quick in judging. This will hurt the traffic and reputation of the site.

Comment: I'm quite the opposite.. I am too quick in Upvoting questions and sometimes realize that wasn't worth it. lol

Answer (score 4):

Please guys do not act quickly when upvoting or downvoting a question or answer.  Please take time to read and understand the question or answer properly.  If it is worth Downvoting than suggest an edit, or try to fix the question or answer in comments.  Slow and steady wins the race, meaning do not rush to up vote or Downvote something, be steady and the question or answer will Insha'Allah win the race (I hope you guys understand this last part.).